# Vue js array reverse causing error in v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am trying to make the array reverse but its throwing a error shown below

in promise) Error: Maximum recursive updates exceeded. This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

i searched it on google and found the array.slice.reverse() instead of directly array.reverse().
it which works fine but i want the index number same as  the orginal array has. is  there any solution to directly reverse the  array

```
<template
              v-for="services in customerReceipt.invoiceServices
                .slice()
                .reverse()"
              :key="services"
            >
              <tr
                class="service_row_cls"
                :class="{ expressReceipt: services.express == 'express' }"
              >
                <td>
                  <Button
                    :label="parseString(services.qty)"
                    @click="adjustServiceQty(services, services.id)"
                    class="p-button-success p-pl-2 p-pr-2 p-pt-0 p-pb-0"
                  />
                </td>
</tr>
</template>

    adjustServiceQty(service, serviceIndex) {
        this.checkTxn.getServicesCoupon(service.serviceId).then((data) => {
          const d = this.camelizeKeys(data);
          this.couponList = d.serviceCoupons;
          this.fixedExpressToday = Number(d.expressAmount);
        });
    
        this.serviceDialog = true;
        this.serviceIndex = serviceIndex;
        this.itemQty = service.qty;
        this.serviceDesc = service.description;
        this.serviceExpressDate = service.dueDate;
        this.serviceExpressTime = service.dueTime;
        this.discountId = service.discountId;
        this.express = service.express;
      }

//HERE I AM CALLING THE BELOW FUNCTION AFTER UPDATING THE QUATITY FROM DIALOG.
//I AM DOING THIS USING FOREACH LOOP WHICH IS SCANING THE ENTIRE ARRAY.
// I JUST WANT TO UPDATE THE QTY USING ARRAY INDEX

    closeServicePopup(params) {
        console.log(params);
        if (params[0] == "Done") {
          this.receiptServices.forEach((e) => {
            if (Number(e.id) == this.serviceIndex) {
              e.express = params[5];
    
              if (params[5] == "express") {
                e.dueDate = params[4];
                e.dueTime = params[3];
              } else {
                e.dueDate = "";
                e.dueTime = "";
              }
    
             e.description = params[2];
             e.expressAmt = 15;
             e.discountId = params[6];
             e.discountMethod = params[8];
             e.discountName = params[7];
             e.discount = Number(params[9]);
             e.qty = Number(params[1]);
            }
          });
        } else if (params[0] == "Cancel") {
          this.toast.showSuccess("Service adjustment cancelled successfully");
        }
    
        this.serviceDialog = false;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow this pattern: `action (click) -> state change (change qty) -> re-render (automatic)`, the same pattern uses `Vuex` library.

In state change you can do all the *magic*.

> NOTE: `reverse` method reverses original array, not returning new array with reversed values.

If you want to get index of item in reversed array, then try following code:

```js
const reversedIdx = (array, idx) => array.length - 1 - idx

const a = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
const b = Array.from(a).reverse()

const a_someIdx = 1 // index of value 11
const b_sameItem = b[reversedIdx(b, a_someIdx)] // 11

console.log(b_sameItem) // 11
```

Comment: yes i did the same but i want the same index number beacuse i am doing edit in orignal array. with array.slice().reverse()  doing job but making index number different

Comment: Provide code! I don't know what are you trying to do, I'll help you...

Comment: ok showing you the code my prob is i need to update the array using index and want to show the array list in reverse order.

Comment: when doing click on adjustServiceQty function i want to update the qty of array index.Right now i am using foraech loop to find that index using id. just beacuse i am using array.slice().reverse().

Comment: Please see updated post. I hope I understood you now.